# Evaluate $\cos (-2\pi)$ using radiants graph

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I plotted $2\pi$ on the $\cos$ graph and the result was $1$, so I assumed $-2\pi$ would be $-1$, but it turned out to be $1$.

Can someone explain how to work this out?

Comment: It is actually $1$. $\cos$ is an *even function*, meaning $\cos x = \cos -x$ for all $x$. (Can you plot $\cos x$ over an interval that covers $-2\pi$?)

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. How do I graph -2pi? Do I just make it 2pi? If so what is the point of ever putting a negative value in the equation?

Comment: I have no idea what the point of this question is. If you are given a graph of $\cos$ on an interval that does not contain $-2\pi$, I believe you're supposed to guess how the function should extend. If you can "graph" $\cos$, then you must have access to the value of $\cos(x)$ for any $x$, and you can just plug in $x = -2\pi$ to get a number.

Comment: I just don't understand why cos(x)=cos(-X) and why sin(-x)=sin(-x)

Comment: That is why I suggest you graph the function over an interval that covers the origin. Or you can think about the unit circle and how $\cos$ is defined from the unit circle. $\cos(x)$ is the projection of the point at angle $x$ (radian) onto the $x$-axis. When you start at angle $0$, you get $1$. Moving up or down from $0$ by the same angle gives you the same point on the $x$-axis. This, in a sense, implies $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$.
(By the way, you wrote $\sin(-x) = \sin(-x)$. That is always true. I guess you meant $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$.)

Comment: When you understand the definitions of sine and cosine as $y$ and $x$, respectively, for a point $(x,y)$ on the unit circle, then all will be clear. Generally speaking, understanding proceeds from knowledge of the relevant definitions.

Comment: It's all okay. I was thinking that you could only go right in the positive x direction on the graph. Then someone pointed out I can go negative, problem solved. Cosine is an even function. Sine is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed: $\cos(-2\pi) = \cos(2\pi) = 1$. Formally, this is because $\cos \theta$ is an even function, meaning $\cos\theta = \cos(−\theta)$ for all $\theta$.

This can be seen in a number of ways. Try graphing $y = \cos x$ over the interval, say, $(-2\pi, 2\pi)$. For quick intuition, we can use, e.g., [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20=%20cos%20x):

[image]

Another factor to remember is that $\cos\theta$ is periodic, with period $2\pi$. So at any integer $k$ multiple of $2\pi$, $$\cos(2k\pi) = \cos(0) = \cos(2\pi) = 1$$ An easy way to convince yourself that this is the case is to recall that every integer multiple of $2\pi$ describes one or more *full* rotations about the unit circle. So $\cos(2k \pi) = \cos(0) = 1$.

Comment: Pictures, explanation +1

Comment: I love the answeres which contains graphs +)

Answer (score 2):

$cos(x)=cos(-x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$, $cos(x) $ is an even function that why.